# Best way to deal with SSO in intranet

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, sharepoint

Overview on use-case, what we trying to achieve:

Two servers, on two different domains; Available only from inside (intranet)

- SharePoint 2013, on https://shp.mydomain.com; (Claims-based authentication)
- ASP.NET Web Api, on https://api.mydomain.com (? authentication); Enabled CORS for sharepoint origin.

User login into SharePoint, clicks on button - calls CORS Ajax request to the api.mydomain.com.

Therefore I would like to auth users from SharePoint to the other app without additional login prompt (SSO). For example, domain\testuser login into SharePoint, and after sending javascript ajax to 'the other app', he will be authenticated there as 'domain\testuser'

The problem is, which authentication for Web API should we use? There are few candidates:

1. Kerberos - however as far as I know, it will require end users to configure our servers 
   as 'trusted sites', in Firefox, IE/Chrome and also some regedit modifications in Chrome... Maybe there is a way to avoid such complicated configuration for end-users?
2. OAuth2 - although I have no idea how to use it with ActiveDirectory
3. Use Claims-based auth from SharePoint - we could put inside the AJAX token from STS, therefore token will be available from JS - isn't it a security issue?
4. Custom Auth (would like to avoid this at all costs)
5. Your idea?

**We cannot use ADFS because SharePoint 2013 is having issues with it.**

What do you think about it? Which option will be the best for us and end-users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used my custom OAuth2 authorization provider.

Flow:

1. User access SharePoint
2. SharePoint calls webApi /token OAuth2 impersonating current user
3. WebApi returns token
4. Token is returned to the user, now he can use it for api calls
5. Only SharePoint calls to /token are allowed (SSL only)

Works pretty well.